# Invoking Drive API through Google App Scripts front-end fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am building an application for Google Sheets through Google App Scripts where I want users access their files through the Google File Picker and then perform operations on these files on our back-end.

Where things break is when we attempt to use the "drive.file" scope instead of just "drive". We need the stricter scope so that our add-on is verified in just a few days rather than 2 months and also to make it safer for the users. According to the scope, we should be able to access only files that are picked / opened by the users through the application; however, it seems to fail as await gapi.client.drive.files.get(...) would return "File not found" for whatever file is picked. Another weird behaviour is that thumbnails are no longer shown and instead, we can see only white and grey squares for every file thumbnail.

Below you can find a minimal reproducible code. In the appsscript.json we set the scopes. In Main.gs we define a function onOpen to add "Select files" option to the context menu, through which we call showFilesDialog and display an HTML with a File Picker (chooseFilesDialog.html). The latter calls getOAuthToken through "google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker).getOAuthToken()" to initialize an access_token from Main.gs and then pass that access_token in createPicker.

appsscript.json:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Sofia",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {},
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
  ]
}
```

Main.gs:

```
function getOAuthToken() {
    return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Select files', 'showFilesDialog')
        .addToUi();
}
function showFilesDialog() {
    try {
        const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('chooseFilesDialog.html')
            .setWidth(600)
            .setHeight(425)
            .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select files or folders.');
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

chooseFilesDialog.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
    <script>
        // IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
        // from the Google Developers Console.
        const DEVELOPER_KEY = '';
        var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = { width: 600, height: 425 };
        var pickerApiLoaded = false;

        /**
         * Loads the Google Picker API.
         */
        function onApiLoad() {
            gapi.load('client:picker', {
                'callback': async function () {
                    await gapi.client.load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest');
                    pickerApiLoaded = true;
                    getOAuthToken();
                }
            });
        }

        function getOAuthToken() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker).getOAuthToken();
        }

        function createPicker(token) {
            console.log("token", token);
            console.log("pickerApiLoaded", pickerApiLoaded);
            gapi.client.setToken({
              access_token: token
            });
            console.log("test", test);
            if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
                // TODO: Remove .setEnableDrives(false);
                var pdfsView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.PDFS)
                    .setLabel("PDFs")
                    //.setOwnedByMe(true);
                    .setIncludeFolders(true)

                var imagesView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS_IMAGES)
                    .setLabel("Images")
                    //.setOwnedByMe(true);
                    .setIncludeFolders(true);

                var spreadsheetsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
                    .setIncludeFolders(true)
                    //.setOwnedByMe(true)
                    .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,text/csv')
                    .setLabel("Spreadsheets");

                var textsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
                    .setIncludeFolders(true)
                    //.setOwnedByMe(true)
                    .setMimeTypes('text/plain')
                    .setLabel("Texts");

                var foldersView = new google.picker.DocsView()
                    .setIncludeFolders(true)
                    //.setOwnedByMe(true)
                    .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
                    .setSelectFolderEnabled(true)
                    .setLabel("Folders");

                var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView()
                    .setIncludeFolders(true)
                    .setMimeTypes('image/jpeg,image/png,application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,text/csv,text/plain');

                var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                    .addView(pdfsView)
                    .addView(imagesView)
                    .addView(spreadsheetsView)
                    .addView(textsView)
                    .addView(foldersView)
                    .addView(uploadView)
                    .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                    .hideTitleBar()
                    .setOAuthToken(token)
                    .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
                    .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                    .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
                    .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
                        DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
                    .build();
                picker.setVisible(true);
            }
        }

        function getExtension(mimeType) {
            const mimeTypeToExtension = {
                "application/vnd.google-apps.folder": "folder",
                "application/pdf": "pdf",
                "image/jpeg": "jpg",
                "image/png": "png",
                "application/vnd.ms-excel": "xls",
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": "xlsx",
                "text/csv": "csv",
                "text/plain": "txt"
            };
            return mimeTypeToExtension[mimeType];
        }

        async function pickerCallback(data) {
            var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
            if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                var docs = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS];
                var filesProperties = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                    var doc = docs[i];
                    var fileId = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
                    var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
                    var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
                    var mimeType = doc[google.picker.Document.MIME_TYPE];
                    var extension = getExtension(mimeType);

                    const res = await gapi.client.drive.files.get({
                        'fileId': fileId,
                    });
                    console.log("res", res);                    
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>

</html>
```